# Problem while writing PDF to password protect PDF using PyPDF2 in Python

Tags: python, pypdf

## This is the code

```
import PyPDF2,os
output = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
input_stream = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open("/root/Desktop/temp_dir/Mr praveen.pdf", "rb"))

for i in range(0, input_stream.getNumPages()):
        output.addPage(input_stream.getPage(i))

outputstream = open("/root/Desktop/name.pdf", "wb")
output.encrypt("mani", use_128bit=True)
output.write(outputstream)
outputStream.close()
```

When running this code , I am getting error

raise utils.PdfReadError("Unable to find 'endstream' marker after stream at byte %s." % utils.hexStr(stream.tell()))
PyPDF2.utils.PdfReadError: Unable to find 'endstream' marker after stream at byte 0xa721.
Please help me.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pwd.py", line 12, in <module>
    output.write(outputstream)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyPDF2/pdf.py", line 482, in write
    self._sweepIndirectReferences(externalReferenceMap, self._root)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyPDF2/pdf.py", line 571, in _sweepIndirectReferences  self._sweepIndirectReferences(externMap, realdata)

Comment: Where there is "self._sweepIndirectReferences(externalReferenceMap, self._root)" called in pdf.py of PyPDF2 library at those lines the error is encountered with output.stream() method .

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyPDF2/generic.py", line 66, in readObject
    return DictionaryObject.readFromStream(stream, pdf)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyPDF2/generic.py", line 636, in readFromStream

Comment: This happens to me every now and then with some PDF files, but I don't know a solution. Just in case, you can try calling the `PdfFileReader` with an argument `strict=False` (but that didn't help in my case).

Comment: Btw you have case mismatch `outputstream` / `outputStream` in your code.

Comment: Thank you but the error persists . Haven't you tried to PyPDF officials in Github ?

Answer (score 0):

`pypdf` got massively improved in 2022. Update your code ([see migration guide](https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/migration-1-to-2.html)) and try again.

The issue is that the PDF you're using is not standard-compliant. We added lots of robustness fixes so that pypdf can deal with non-compliant PDF documents, but it would be best to just fix the PDF.

### Fixing broken PDF documents

mutools from MuPDF can fix broken PDF documents:

```
mutool clean -d input.pdf output.pdf
```